# Need assistance me with this Excel Task? Unable to generate the proper results

Tags: excel, indexing, return, match, formula

Looking for help with this task. Here's is a portion of the table I'm working with:
[image]

What I'm trying to do is have the cells in Column B (MWD) return the value of the adjacent cells in Column C (Pseudo). Column A (Data Set) has the same values as Colum B but including duplicates. I need a formula where the duplicates in Column A will return the same value that it matches in column B.

Example: I need...

all the duplicate 1010001's to return pseudo 1
all the duplicate 1020001's to return pseudo 2
all the duplicate 1020002's to return pseudo 3

and so on...

I was trying to use index match function but don't know if I'm constructing the formula wrong or if it's the correct formula to use.

Comment: Is data sorted by col A?

Answer (score 0):

If data is sorted by column A, you can use one formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:A2,A2)>1,C1,C1+1)
```

if not, then other

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:A2,A2)>1,INDEX($C$1:C2,MATCH(A2,$A$1:A2,0)),MAX($C$1:C1)+1)
```

in both cases copy the formula in second row (in C2 cell in my examples). To the first row add `1` manually.

First example:

[image]

Second example:

[image]

Comment: Okay thank you so much but there's still a slight problem... The function works great but the count gets thrown off. here's another example from the same data: